# Drag - connect an UISwitch to an IBOutlet on a delegate class

Tags: xcode, swift

My goal is to enable/disable the editing of a UITextField with a UISwitch using delegates. This is the delegate class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SwitchedTextFieldDelegate :  NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var switchText : UISwitch!

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    //Here I intended to read the UISwitch state 

    print("Can't touch this")

    return false
    }

}
```

I've tried to drag-connect the IBOutlet to the storyboard, but it is not possible. I can do it on the main view controller, which inherits UIViewController. I've already learned that multiple inheritance is not possible in Swift. How would you solve this? I'll try using an IBAction instead.

Comment: It is common to use the view controller itself as the delegate. You can use a separate class as the delegate if you want but you won't be able to connect the delegate using the storyboard. You will have to do it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main view controller drag IBOutlet of a UITextField and UISwitch. Then confirm the UITextField Delegate. Now implement the UITextField Delegate method Like this:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if switchText.on{

      return true

    }else{

      return false
    }
  }
```

For better understanding I have shared my ViewController screen shot.Here FirstViewController is just like your MainViewController. Hope this will help you.

[image]